# WordPress won't let me change my administration email address :(

Tags: wordpress, email

I'm trying to set my domain name email (something like username@mywebiste.com) to be the one that my website users can send messages to when they click on "send messages" on my website. I put my personal email for my administration email when I signed up for WordPress and now I want to change it to my domain name email. I went to WordPress Dashboard --> Settings --> General, I typed my domain name email and clicked on save changes and nothing changed. It still has my personal email as my admin email. How can I fix this?

Just FYI, I'm a total beginner with no code knowledge who has just started learning on making my own website with a store bought theme. So I would appreciate if you can explain in simple and easy ways. Thank you in advance:)
Have a great day!

Comment: Since this isn't a programming question but a WordPress troubleshooting question you may have a better chance at getting useful answers here instead: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Have you checked your domain email inbox for the confirmation email, because after you change the admin email for word press it sends a confirmation email to the email address you entered, and only after you click the confirm link in that mail the address will be changed on website.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This is a site for coding-related questions. Please review ["What topics can I ask about here?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) to see what you can ask here and the best way to ask it so you get the help you need. For questions that are not coding related, try asking on the relevant site from the list of [other StackExchange sites]()https://stackexchange.com/sites#technology